# How to run a website on a subdomain when the root domain is hosted elsewhere

Tags: ssl, dns, cpanel

## Scenario:

I have built a job board for a client and am running that website on my server while the client’s main website is still hosted in its original location.

- client.com (root) is on client’s server
- jobs.client.com on my server
- “jobs” is set up on client.com as an “A” record pointing to the IP address of my server. A real subdomain has not been created on client.com’s server.

## Problem:

I am getting a SSL error because it seems jobs.client.com is not covered by a certificate.

## Question:

Is it just a matter of time before client.com’a certificate provider will detect and cover the new subdomain?

Or will I need to add a certificate to jobs.client.com on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it just a matter of time before client.com’a certificate provider will detect and cover the new subdomain?

No.

> Or will I need to add a certificate to jobs.client.com on my server?

Yes. The certificate covering the hostname specified in the URL needs to be explicitly installed at the server which serves this hostname. It is unclear what kind of certificate your server currently provides, but likely the wrong one.